# How to send email with UITableView

Tags: ios, email, uitableview, send

So I'm using this array to display email addresses in a custom table cell

```
 EmailAddress = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"sample@aths.ac.ae",:@"sample@aths.ac.ae",:@"sample@aths.ac.ae", :@"sample@aths.ac.ae",:@"sample@aths.ac.ae",:@"sample@aths.ac.ae", nil];
```

and I used this code for my email but I always get a SIGABRT error whenever I press the cell

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    MFMailComposeViewController *controller = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
    controller.mailComposeDelegate = self;
    NSArray *toRecipients = [EmailAddress objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    [controller setToRecipients:toRecipients];
    [controller setTitle:@""];
    [controller setSubject:@""];
    [controller setMessageBody:@"" isHTML:NO];

    if(UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM()==UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad)
    {
        controller.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFormSheet;
    }
    else
    {
        controller.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFullScreen;
    }
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];

}


    - (void)mailComposeController:(MFMailComposeViewController*)controller didFinishWithResult:(MFMailComposeResult)result error:(NSError*)error {
    [self becomeFirstResponder];
    NSString *strMailResult;
    switch (result)
    {
        case MFMailComposeResultCancelled:
            strMailResult = NSLocalizedString(@"E-Mail Cancelled",@"");
            break;
        case MFMailComposeResultSaved:
            strMailResult = NSLocalizedString(@"E-Mail Saved",@"");
            break;
        case MFMailComposeResultSent:
            strMailResult = NSLocalizedString(@"E-Mail Sent",@"");
            break;
        case MFMailComposeResultFailed:
            strMailResult = NSLocalizedString(@"E-Mail Failed",@"");
            break;
        default:
            strMailResult = NSLocalizedString(@"E-Mail Not Sent",@"");
            break;
    }

    UIAlertView* alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"Message",@"") message:strMailResult delegate:self  cancelButtonTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"OK",@"") otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alertView show];
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

but I end up with the error I think the error is from the `toRecipient` but I dont know how to fix it.

Comment: What is the error you are getting ?

Comment: why do u have ":" in you `NSArray` of `EmailAddress`

Comment: Where does the error happen?

Comment: You are trying to create an `NSArray *toReceipents` from an object of `EmailAddress`… that won't create an array like that

Comment: change `NSArray *toRecipients = [EmailAddress objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];` to this and try…     `NSArray *toRecipients = [NSArray arrayWithObject:[EmailAddress objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];` should work

Comment: email is send using  ' MFMailComposeViewController ' not a tableViewController.

Comment: AliAlM show the answer here in some form and maybe you can get an upvote for being constructive.

Answer (score 3):

One obvious problem is with the following two lines:

```
NSArray *toRecipients = [EmailAddress objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
[controller setToRecipients:toRecipients];
```

It should be:

```
NSString *toRecipient = [EmailAddress objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
[controller setToRecipients:@[ toRecipient ]];
```

since you only get a single recipient value from the `EmailAddress` array.

Comment: almost same solution i wrote :)

Comment: @AhmedZ. Obviously we were typing at the same time. Why post an answer in the comments?

Comment: Thanks! i just fixed the problem myself but with a different way!